# Vue 3 HighchartsVue

Tags: highcharts, vuejs3

Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined.

I'm working Vue3 App.

On my `app.js` file I have declared,

```
import HighchartsVue from 'highcharts-vue';

createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        return createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .use(ZiggyVue, Ziggy)
            .use(HighchartsVue)
            .mount(el);
    }
});
```

Then on my component.vue file, I can use `<highcharts>` component with no problem.

However I cannot use `Highcharts.dateFormat()` method,
it returns an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined`

I'm trying to apply it on this tooltip.

```
tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return 'Amount' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%e %b %Y', this.x);
        }
    },
```

How can I use `Highcharts.dateFormat()` method on Vuejs using options API?

Answer (score 1):

you need import it befor using

```js
import Highcharts from 'highcharts'

...

tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return 'Amount' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%e %b %Y', this.x);
        }
    },
```